# Why is there a spike in voltage over an inductor double the peak voltage of a square wave input?

Tags: signal, voltage-measurement

I am trying to understand why a graph looks like this for the voltage over an inductor in an LR circuit. The square wave is an input voltage and the red decaying wave is the voltage across the inductor.[image]

I came up with this graph using step functions and the step response of the inductor.

The only reason I can think of is that the inductor has stored energy, but it seems also that the inductor dissipates that energy after five time constants. Where is this extra voltage coming from?

Comment: LR series or LR parallel? Its much easier to just draw the circuit than describe it in words. Yes, inductors store energy in the form of a magnetic field and yes after 5 time constants the energy is discharged but you'll find this info in just about any any article about inductors along with an explanation of back e.m.f. when the magnetic field collapses. That's why we put a reverse polarity connected diode across inductors to short out the back e.m.f. and prevent damage to BJTs etc.

Comment: For a LR series circuit. I wrote the circuit down on paper and realized that because the current in the inductor does not change instantaneously, the resistor will still have a voltage across it. Using KVL I got from the same result as the graph at 5 tau.

Answer (score 4):

It is useful to remember the inductor constitutive relationship: $$v_L(t)= L \frac{di_L(t)}{dt} $$
That is, the voltage across an inductor is proportional to the **derivative of the current** through it.

When you apply a constant voltage of, say, 1V at the input node (I assume your circuit resembles that of the schematic below) there will be a constant current flowing on the resistor, so the inductor will behave as a **short-circuit**, thus presenting a zero voltage drop (look at your plot: the red curve actually tends to zero!!!).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpyi5Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the voltage at the input drops, inductor current continuity imposes the same current to flow as before,so the same voltage drop across the resistor -as before. Hence the additional negative voltage across the inductor.
Similar considerations also hold for the positive step.

One may wooden why steps in inductor current cannot occur. 
Actually, when inductor current steps show up, something different will occur before the voltage goes to infinity, for example a spark when you open a switch lacking the suitable protection (normally provided by a **freewheeling diode** in power applications).

---

From a mathematical standpoint, it is physically feasible to force a voltage (not current!!!) step across an inductor and a current (not voltage!!!) step across a capacitor; BEWARE: I am talking about steps applied to the inductor (or capacitor), NOT to the overall circuit. 
If you have some knowledge of control system theory, this is dubbed as the principle of integral causality. But I don't want to go deeper in that.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Since this is being voted positive, I need to point out the explanations here is not really correct in a few places. "there is a (negative) step in the inductor current", there is no negative step in the current. "the red curve going to infinity.", the red curve does not go to infinity, it is the value of the input step voltage. ...

Comment: Ok thanks, I edited the post accordingly. The limited scope of the chart prevented me from figuring out the actual waveform

Comment: Free-wheeling-diodes are also used with small relays in electronic circuits.  In simple terms:  when the relay is switched off the voltage in the inductor is equal to the change in current and this high voltage is prevented by adding the diode.

Comment: Yes, let's say that it 'pins' the voltage to the diode's forward drop while providing the inductor current with an alternative path

Answer (score 1):

Let's start at the end of a step change when the voltage across the inductor is near zero. A voltage step occurs, the current through the inductor is continuous. The current through the resistor is the same as the inductor and is therefore continuous. The voltage across the resistor is continuous because of Ohm's law. The full voltage step appears across the inductor.

The voltage step is the peak to peak voltage, and is 2 times the "symmetrical" voltage and that is the voltage across the inductor.

There is no "extra voltage", it is simply the input step voltage.

The role the stored energy of the inductor plays in this would go like this - the stored energy is in the form of magnetic flux, the flux has to be continuous therefore the current has to be continuous.